# Lubuntu and URL shortcuts not working

Tags: lubuntu, browser

If I drag the address bar (from Chrome) onto the Lubuntu 2204 LTS desktop I get a menu "Copy here" or "Symlink here". I expect (and hope) that is the way to create a desktop shortcut to the URL.

Choosing either one does...nothing. No new icon appears on the desktop.

Is there a fix?

And if it can be made to work, what's the difference between the 2 choices?

Comment: Some details on using desktop shortcuts are provided in the manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/5/5.2/desktop_icons.html), did you look?   Sorry I don't use `chrome` thus am not sure how much it differs to the `chromium` (snap) found in Ubuntu repositories so won't comment on it.

Comment: Thanks; I've been meaning to read that fine manual. I will now before asking more questions.

Comment: @guiverc I looked at the manual page you linked; I didn't see any mention of web browsers or URLs - the closest thing was a mention that you can "create shortcuts by dragging and dropping files and folders from the File manager onto the desktop". But I'm trying to drag-n-drop from a web browser. I tried with the pre-installed Firefox - choices are "Copy here" (does nothing), "Move here" (does nothing), "Create symlink here" - pops up an error "! Cannot create a link on non-native filesystem". That's on top of the dialog "Create Symlinks". (Destination: /home/dave/Desktop) So I'm still stuck.

Comment: `firefox` as comes with Ubuntu/Lubuntu 22.04 is a *snap* package, which differs to the *deb* package `chrome` comes with by default; I'd look at what was created by `chrome` and hopefully work out what was required using the details in the manual.  Desktop shortcuts *may* or *may not* appear on the desktop (*even if created!*) depending on your choice on them being shown (maybe helpful - https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.5/desktop.html).  Creation refers to creating in `$HOME/Desktop` but they only show on your desktop IF you have them showing by setting.

Comment: FYI:  My description maybe unclear as I prefer a clean desktop (no icons) so have all disabled.. and only QA test then rarely (once per cycle [*meaning every six months*] to ensure I can get them working, which isn't often enough for me to remember clearly how they work). If you're using the backports PPA to get the newer LXQt desktop; use the *stable* version of the manual; ie. replace the *LTS* in the manual links to use *STABLE*, ie. you'll use the 22.10 manual which has the later version of LXQt (*closest to 22.04 with backports*)

Comment: @guiverc I definitely don't have "Hide Desktop Items" selected, if that's what you mean. I see a dozen other desktop icons just fine (Computer, user, Network,Trash, QTerminal, Google Chrome, etc.).